# TLB flush on a switch from kernel to user UNIX

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-memory, flush, tlb, user-mode-linux

I was looking for an answer for this question but didn't find any clear answer.
When calling a sys call such as `getpid()`, while returning from kernel mode to user mode, does the TLB get flushed?

My "logic" says yes, in order to prevent the user to invades kernel's address space.
I am not very convinced with that answer because of the hardware protection which can protect the kernel's virtual space and save flushing time.

Would love to get this straight,

Thanks.

Comment: There certainly is such hardware protection - there's a user/supervisor bit in every page table entry, so kernel memory can be left mapped without making it accessible to the user.  However I seem to recall that as part of the Meltdown/Spectre mitigations, the user now gets a separate page table with kernel memory not mapped at all, and switching between those tables on entry/exit to the kernel would certainly entail a TLB flush.  I'll have to look it up.

Comment: @NateEldredge yep, that's called Page Table Isolation aka PTI, usually enabled by default.